# Google AutoValue does not recognise AutoValue_CustomType

Tags: java, android, gradle, auto-value

I am trying to use Google AutoValue to generate HomeKey in my Android Studio project, but it does not recignose AutoValue_HomeKey() (see in the commented code below). The used gradle version: 4.10.1

My Android project is based on this example one:
https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack/tree/master/simple-stack-example-basic-java-fragment

Did I forgot to apply a plugin, or implemented a wrong package?

HomeKey class:

```
import com.google.auto.value.AutoValue;

@AutoValue
public abstract class HomeKey extends BaseKey {
    public static HomeKey create() {

        /*
            Cannot resolve AutoValue_HomeKey()
        */
        return new AutoValue_HomeKey(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected BaseFragment createFragment() {
        return new HomeFragment();
    }
}
```

BaseKey class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import gamf.tankolaskonyvelo.fragment.BaseFragment;

public abstract class BaseKey implements Parcelable {
    public String getFragmentTag() {
        return toString();
    }

    public final BaseFragment newFragment() {
        BaseFragment fragment = createFragment();
        Bundle bundle = fragment.getArguments();
        if (bundle == null) {
            bundle = new Bundle();
        }
        bundle.putParcelable("KEY", this);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    protected abstract BaseFragment createFragment();
    }
}
```

Project level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "gamf.tankolaskonyvelo"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-    core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.Zhuinden:simple-stack:1.13.4'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'

    implementation "com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.2"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.6.2"
    annotationProcessor 'frankiesardo:auto-parcel:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Hello, the `AutoValue_` classes should show up after you try to `Rebuild Project` the project at least once. You are not using Kotlin, so `annotationProcessor` scope should handle that as is. One thing you are missing is `clojars` repository, which is used by `auto-parcel` (IIRC).

Comment: So try adding `maven { url "https://clojars.org/repo/" }` to your repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `annotationProcessor 'frankiesardo:auto-parcel:1.0.3'` which is hosted on `clojars`.

So you should add the following repository to your `allprojects {` block in  build.gradle:

```
maven { url "https://clojars.org/repo/" }
```

Then you should try to Rebuild Project.

After successful build, the classes generated by annotation processing should show up.

---

(if you check the repo's root build.gradle, then you see the maven repos that the samples *might* use:

> ```
> repositories {
>     google()
>     mavenCentral()
>     maven { url "https://clojars.org/repo/" }
>     maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
>     maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
>     jcenter()
> }
> ```

so even if the library itself is hosted on `jitpack.io`, the sample's dependency `auto-parcel` is on clojars)